# SWTableViewCell If table view scrolls showing utility buttons disappear

Tags: ios, iphone, swipe

For example:
There is a tableview with 100 rows, user opens left utility button first row of tableview,
and scroll to the bottom of table view and then when scroll to top of table view, opened utility button closes.

How can i do always stay open opened cells.

Thank you.

my code is here:

```
            AiTableCellControllerTableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"InboxCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell setLeftUtilityButtons:[self cellLeftButtons] WithButtonWidth:32.0f];
        cell.delegate = self;

        cell.tag = indexPath.row;
        UILabel *lbl1 = cell.lbl1;
        UILabel *lbl2 = cell.lbl2;
        UILabel *lbl3 = cell.lbl3;
        UILabel *lbl4 = cell.lbl4;
        UIImageView *imageView = cell.ImageView1;

        imageView.hidden = [[[[inboxArray valueForKey:@"MailboxContentItem"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"PacketNoteList"] count] == 0; //not yoksa gizliyoruz uyari ikonunu

        NSString *dateStr = [[inboxArray valueForKey:@"EntryDate"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@", [dateStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 2)], [dateStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)], [dateStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)]];

        lbl1.text = [[inboxArray valueForKey:@"ShipmentCompany"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lbl2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[inboxArray valueForKey:@"PacketCode"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], dateStr];
        lbl3.text = [[inboxArray valueForKey:@"Content"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        lbl4.text = [[inboxArray valueForKey:@"WeightInfo"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
```

Comment: Please post the code from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: I updated my question @ZeMoon thanks